# Please hepl me about Access Query

Tags: ms-access

```
Select * From tableA, TableB INNER JOIN tableC ON TableB.X = tableC.Y  ==>OK

Select * From tableA, TableB LEFT JOIN tableC ON TableB.X = tableC.Y   ==>ERROR
```

I replace the "LEFT JOIN" with "INNER JOIN" => Error

Comment: What is the error ?

Answer (score 0):

The error he gets is `JOIN Expression not supported`.

@VanThuyet:
You have to provide the join via a sub query:

```
Select * From tableA, (Select * From TableB LEFT JOIN tableC ON TableB.X = tableC.Y) As BC
```

Comment: Good idea. Thanks you for the reply.